# react-router version 3.x behaving differently on different browsers

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reactive-programming

I have made an application using react-router version 3.x.x, The problem is react-router does not behave correctly.

Given:

```
Loginpath: http://example.net/#/login
dontloginpath: http://example.net/#/dontlogin
contact us: http://example.net/#/contactus
```

I am using hashhistory to load the same path on reload.
I have only one bundle.js file.

Problem Statement: Now If I am on ContactUS page (which has nothing to do with login) and reload the application using ctrl+f5(in windows), then it goes to login page in some machines and works fine in other machines. This is happening on production environment, however it works fine in local environment..

***How do I debug it ?
do react-routes have any thing to do with caching/localstorage?***